# Handle class behaving like union

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory-method, chain-of-responsibility

I have a case that I want return an object that is populated by multiple concrete classes.
Specific example:

```
public interface MovieHandler {
    UserPreferences process(Context context, Customer customer, History customerHistory);
}
```

Concrete implementations:

```
public class AdventureMovieHandler implements MovieHandler
public class ComedyMovieHandler implements MovieHandler
public class MysteryMovieHandler implements MovieHandler
public class SciFiMovieHandler implements MovieHandler
```

Each has their own logic so that based on the parameters passed in the `process` the create a list of recommendation for the specific category/genre.

There is also:

```
public class Recommender {
    private List<UserPreferences> handlers;

    public Recommender() {
        handlers = new ArrayList<>();
        handlers.add(new AdventureMovieHandler());
        handlers.add(new ComedyMovieHandler());
        handlers.add(new SciFiMovieHandler());
        handlers.add(new MysteryMovieHandler());
    }

    public UserPreferences getRecommendations(Context context, Customer customer, History customerHistory) {
        UserPreferences preferences = new UserPreferences();
        for(MovieHandler handler: handlers) {
            UserPreferences r = handler.process(context, customer, customerHistory);
            if(r.getMysteryInfo() != null) {
                preferences.setMysteryInfo(r.getMysteryInfo());
            }
            else if(r.getAdventureInfo() != null) {
                preferences.setAdventureInfo(r.getAdventureInfo());
            }
            else if(r.getComedyInfo() != null) {
                preferences.setComedyInfo(r.getComedyInfo());
            }
            else if(r.getSciFiInfo() != null) {
                preferences.setSciFiInfo(r.getSciFiInfo());
            }
            preferences.getMovies().addAll(r.getMovies());
        }
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

And the `UserPreferences`.

```
public class UserPreferences {
    private MysteryGenre mysteryInfo;
    private AdventureGenre adventureInfo;
    private ComedyGenre comedyInfo;
    private SciFiGenre sciFiInfo;

    List<Movie> movies;
```

Now this works but I am not sure if the implementation of the `Recommender` could use some design pattern that helps avoiding checking for what is `null` per case in the series of `if/else`.
Is there something suited that can be used for this case?
Please note that I need to return that `UserPreferences` in that format i.e. as a holder for all the various cases

Comment: Your original solution works well as long as the concrete classes use the same parameters, as you say.  I'd wait until I had a concrete example of an additional parameter before I'd worry about a `Parameter` class.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Is this "flexibility" not good to be considered early on in the design?

Comment: Not in this case, no.  Your "flexibility" is over-engineering.

Comment: @Michael: Typo, fixed. Thank you